# Create new object in secured method

Tags: java, spring

In an application that use Java Spring is implemented a method with @Secured("ROLE_USER"). In this method I'm not able to create new other objects. However, unable to create other objects in this method depends on @Secured? How can I able to create some object in such a method?

Comment: Your fluency in English is basic and you make many errors with spelling and grammar.  Please refrain from correcting spelling/grammar of other posts until you become fluent in English.

Answer (score 1):

```
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
```

has no effect on the code you are able to write, its a rule for accessibility when the application is deployed.